# post without changing page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm thinking AJAX is probably the most logical route to my answer, but I can't find a way to use an AJAX post without making my routing convention useless.  As far as I have been able to tell, using

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
```

you can not give the form_for helper an ID- at least, not with 'do |f|' in there.  If I'm understanding this line of code correctly..

```
$("#test").ajaxForm({url: '/posts', type: 'post'})
```

Then I would need to give my form tag an ID.  If that is true, I could get around that by doing

```
<form id="test">
```

But then not only would I have to rename all my helpers, I would have to edit my controller to parse the data posted by the form.  Given the size of my project, that could take a week... and it cuts the potential for scale to an extent.

A synopsis for why I'm doing this-
I have a form that is technically an "edit" page, but it is more of a mix of show, edit, and new.  There is a mix of info from last month's work, edit boxes for last month's work, and new boxes for this month's.  There are four main "blocks" to the page, and each has a separate set of information which may or may not be stored in a separate database table, which may or may not be related to any of the other tables.

It is important for employees to be able to post updates on a regular basis- every few seconds or so.  However, this kills system resources as each time they post, it re-loads the entire page.  I have code bashed out to use AJAX to refresh specific blocks upon button click, but it does me no good if the entire page automatically re-freshes after the post anyway.  Is there a way to either disable the reload in the update action, or to post in a different manner using AJAX so that the page does not refresh/redirect?

Using rails 3.0.20
Using ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371)
Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the form_for docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

The quick answer is you need to add `remote: true` to your form_for.

Comment: Thanks a million, Jason.